# Comment traduire « faff »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Dans les phrases anglaises suivantes :

> Getting that done was a huge faff.
>
> Everyone faffed about for ages before we got started.

Le mot « *faff* » représente les activités inefficaces, souvent ennuyeuses. Il n'existe pas dans mon dictionnaire, est-ce qu'il y a un mot ou une phrase française pour la même idée ?

Comment: Non, les français ne perdent jamais de temps…

Comment: Si *faff* signifie bien activité inutile et le plus souvent ennuyeuse, tu peux t'arrêter sur cette expression. Les propositions données dans les différentes réponses ne sont pas satisfaisantes. Elles peuvent cependant faire l'affaire dans certains cas, cela dépendra du contexte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

J'ai l'impression à lire tes exemples qu'il s'agit dans certains cas de ce que l'on appelle *brasser du vent*, tandis que dans d'autres cas ce serait plutôt *une galère* :

- *Une galère*: activité ennuyeuse, fastidieuse, souvent longue - mais sans en remettre l'utilité en question. Synonyme de *laborieux* :

> Getting that done was a huge faff.
>   En finir avec ce truc s'est révélé *une vraie galère*.

- *Brasser du vent*: faire des choses inutiles, ou si elles sont utiles, les faire de façon inefficace :

> Everyone faffed about for ages before we got started.
>   Tout le monde a *brassé du vent*  pendant des heures avant que l'on ne commence.

Autant le second sens paraît clair, autant je suis moins certain du premier, du fait de la non remise en cause de l'utilité de l'action entreprise. Qu'en penses-tu ?

Comment: J'allais suggérer « brasser de l'air »... Donc +1 à la place. Bonne distinction entre les deux usages, aussi.

Answer (score 9):

Je serais portée à proposer *perte de temps* et *perdre son temps*.

Answer (score 6):

Je dirais *[musarder](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/musarder/verbe)*, ou dans un language plus courant, *[glander](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glander/verbe)* ou *[glandouiller](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glandouiller/verbe)*. J'imagine aussi que la plupart des [synonymes de musarder](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/musarder/verbe) pourraient convenir.

Comment: Glander est beaucoup plus vulgaire que "Faff". De plus, je ne pense pas que ce soit une traduction de l'expression.

Comment: Familier, populaire, je ne dis pas. Mais vulgaire, je pense que c'est un peu dur pour ce pauvre verbe.

Answer (score 2):

Pour le "faff about", pourquoi pas procrastiner ?